# Chain rule for the $\frac{d}{d\mathbf{w}}\exp(-|\mathbf{w}|^2)$: What about the absolute value?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My question is about the vector derivative $\frac{d}{d\mathbf{v}}\exp(-|w|^2)$. If I apply the chain rule I get $-2\mathbf{w}\exp(-|\mathbf{w}|^2)$ , is this correct or can I leave out the absolute value. Why is or isn't the absolute value necessary? Should the answer be $-2|\mathbf{w}|\hat{w}\exp(-|\mathbf{w}|^2)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute value is unnecessary because $w^2\geq0$ anyways. Recall the definition of absolute value: $
|x| =
\begin{cases}
x, & \text{if }x\geq0 \\
-x, & \text{if }x<0
\end{cases}$.
 Therefore $|w|^2=|w||w|=\begin{cases}
(w)(w)=w^2, & \text{if }w\geq0 \\
(-w)(-w)=w^2, & \text{if }w<0
\end{cases}$. So then, $|w|^2=w^2$ which means that absolute value is unnecessary here.

Comment: What if I have $\mathbf{w}=\mathbf{v-u}$. Then $(\mathbf{v-u})\cdot(\mathbf{v-u})$ is positive but $(\mathbf{v-u})$ is not necessarily.

Comment: In that case you need to apply the chain rule several times, if you're still working with $w$. You also need to classify the different cases of $v-u$.